# SMS send Failed Issue

Tags: android, sms, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm just trying to clarify something.

I'm currently writing a simple bit of code that does the standard listen out for an incoming SMS to a device, upon seeing that it will reply with an auto_sms reply. I've tried it on devices running Android 4.0 + and they seemed to have no issue's, but I've been testing it on two devices that run Android 2.3.4 and 2.3.6 and both are giving me the following error when the code is trying to send the auto_sms reply.

I presume this is down to the versions of Android on the devices that are causing the issues, is there anyway to make the code work with older versions of Android?

```
07-17 03:29:43.710: D/SMSDispatcher(246): mResultReceiver : success = true
07-17 03:29:44.370: D/SMSDispatcher(246): SMS send failed
```

Here is the code I'm using for my **Location_SMS_Request class**.

```
package com.example.mm_parentapp_sms_commands;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Location_SMS_Request_1 extends Activity {

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    PendingIntent sentPI, deliveredPI;
    BroadcastReceiver smsSentReceiver, smsDeliveredReceiver;
    ContentResolver contentResolver;
    ContentObserver smsContentObserver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
        contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //---create the BroadcastReceiver when the SMS is sent---
        smsSentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio Off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        smsDeliveredReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        //---register the two BroadcastReceivers---
        registerReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

        //---SEND A SMS MESSAGE---
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage("Response Number Here", null, "Locate", sentPI, deliveredPI);

        smsContentObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                Uri smsURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(smsURI, new String[]{"address", "date", "body", "type"}, null, null, null);

                String[] columns = new String[] {
                        "address", "date", "body", "type"
                };

                //---go to the first rown; which is the most recently 
                // sent message---
                c.moveToNext();

                //---get the various properties of the SMS message---
                String recipient = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
                String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
                String message = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
                String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));

                //---print out the details of the message---
                Log.d("DetectOutgoingSMS", recipient + ", " + date + ", " +
                        message + ", " + type);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, smsContentObserver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        contentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(smsContentObserver);
        //---unregister the two BroadcastReceivers---
        unregisterReceiver(smsSentReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver);

        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the sent message always "Locate"?

Comment: Yeh the message will always have the value of "Locate", as I'm writing an app that allows one user to click a button which will send out a predefined message of "Locate", which will then be received on an App on another device which will be watching for that keyword. The keyword will trigger a request to get the devices current location and return it in another SMS back to the other Device.

Comment: Are you sure the Response Number is valid? Also, are those log entries generated by your app?